# My website does not load since two days!

Tags: wp-admin, shared-hosting

Two days ago I bought a domain alijoohy.com and hosting using hostgator, and installed WordPress but till cannot enter the admin webpage,I don’t know what to do. Could you please help

Comment: Have you asked hostgator for support?

Comment: Did you fix paths in the wp_options after migration? What errors did you get when trying to load wp-admin?